# pip and multiple python version issues in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, pip

I'm deploying a flask server with gulp, and after the gulp command is launched, everything goes fine until the following line:

```
import flask
```

as I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

. Adding the lines before the import command

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I get printed

```
/usr/bin/python
```

which, launched on console, corresponds to a python 2.7.12 interpreter, and the command 'import flask' within the console doesn't give any error!!

I can find many python interpreters (2, 3 and virtenvs on my machine) but it seems each of them has flask installed.

Comment: Try putting `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of your script if you want to use that python. Or you should run `/usr/bin/python app.py` for comparison

Comment: good hint! running "/usr/bin/python app.py" doesn't give the import error. so how can I know which is the actual interpreter that is invoked?

Comment: Well, `python2` would probably be the interpreter you meant to run, but `python` at the CLI and `python app.py` to run the script should give you the same one.